# How to make a div appear if another div is not shown?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make a `<div>` appear if another `<div>` is set to `display:none`?

for example if `<div class="side">` is set to `display:none` I want another `<div>` to display, but only if `.side` is set to `display:none`

Comment: and http://whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: also, `php` can't help you there, you need to use `javascript` (title and tags edited)

Answer (score 2):

Following is what you should be doing,

1: Finding the div with class .side,

2:  checking if this is hidden

3:  showing another div, if 2 is correct

```
if($("body").find(".side").is(':hidden') {  // Ideally You should be finding your .side div within its parent container and not body, to improve performance
  $("youranotherdiv").css("display","block");
})
```